# YUV420 to RGB conversion not giving the same image?

Tags: c++, image-processing, rgb, color-scheme, yuv

I am creating dummy YUV420 image using following code-snippet.I want to create a copy of the same image in RGB format using the Y,U and V components.

I referred Wiki entry on YUV to RGB conversion but it doesnt give the same image as of YUV.
Any suggestions ?

**Edit :** **`img` is a QImage in RGB32 format (ARGB).**

This is YUV420 image :[image]

This is what RGB conversion giving : [image]

```
 int clamp(int val){
        if(val>255) return 255;
        if(val<0) return 0;
        return val;
    }

    -----
    int h=height;
    int w=width;
    for(y=0;y<h ;y++){
        for(x=0;x<w;x++){

               int hy=y/2;
               int hx=x/2;

               //Populate YUV420 image      
               char compY=x+y+i*3; //Y component
               char compU=128+hy+(i)*2; //U component
               char compV=64+hx+(i)*5;  //V component

               //encoder.setInputPicturePixelData(0,y* l0+x,compY);
               //encoder.setInputPicturePixelData(1,hy*l1+hx,compU);                                 //encoder.setInputPicturePixelData(2,hy*l2+hx,compV);
               //encoder.setInputPicturePixelData(2,hy*l2+hx,compV);

              //Now create the RGB image 

               char R=clamp(compY+1.402*(compV-128));
               char G=clamp(compY-0.3444*(compU-128)-0.714*(compV-128));
               char B=clamp(compY+1.772*(compU-128));

               int RGBval=0xFF<<24 | R<<16 |  G<<8 | B;
               img->setPixel(x,y,RGBval);


             }
    }
```

Comment: And what you get is different from YUV in...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> char compY=x+y+i*3;

Your image has width of 359 pixels, and you do not check if x or y are within [0..255] range. The value will probably overflow and wrap around.

> int RGBval=0xFF<<24 | R<<16 |  G<<8 | B;

Qt has qRgb and qRgba functions. You should use them instead of writing macros yourself.

> char R=clamp(compY+1.402*(compV-128));

**In C++ char is normally signed**, and stores valus in range `[-128..127]`. So if you subtract 128 from any positive char value, you'll get negative number. Which is probably not what you want.

Innstead of `char` use `quint8`, `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what is `img`? It can be faulty itself and it might be putting data in a wrong way. It might be expecting R, G, B values in the opposite order (B << 16), or zero alpha bits.

Another thing is that `R`, `G`, `B` are 8 bit values and you are shifting them too much. You should be doing it like this:

```
int RGBval= (0xFF << 24) | ((unsigned int) R << 16) |  ((unsigned int) G << 8) | B;
```

Comment: sorry about that ,img is a QImage instance,in RGB32 format (ARGB)

Comment: Qt has qRgb and qRgba functions. You should use them instead of writing macros yourself.

Answer (score 1):

what's the i in `char compY=x+y+i*3`; 
And what's FourCC code for your YUV420 picture. With only YUV420, we can't know the picture is  [packed formats or  planar formats](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php)

Comment: "i" is an incrementing integer.I am using this code to generate sample video."i" makes the transition between frames.